# Jenkins Workspace not visible on docker slaves

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am having a Master slave setup in jenkins, where all of my slave machines are docker slaves.

I am using Yet another docker plugin to configure these slaves. All my jobs are passing successfully on the slave nodes, but I cannot view the workspace from the jenkins UI. Is this because the container gets destroyed after the build is getting executed successfully? If yes, then what is a work around to view the workspace.

Comment: If you wants to preserver the workspace you need to provide `docker run -it -v host-dir:container-dir $image-name` otherwise it will not preserver the workspace. This feature is called `Volume mount` in docker. Thanks

Comment: will this help me view the workspace in UI?

Comment: Yes, But the condition is it should not stop your container. If you want to stop container than I would recommend use shared storage for persist data of any container and that should be permanently mounted on jenkins UI.

Comment: okay, so well I would want to stop the containers, because there are alot of builds and I would want to clean it up, after the build is done. Can you please elaborate on how to use a shared storage for persisting data?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to persist the storage of all the containers which has been initiated when build triggered and stopped when build finished. correct ?

Let's consider You mount one large partition on as a shared storage. `/opt` or anything of your choice.

So when you triggered build it should initiate container with `docker run -it --name ${JOB_NUMBER} -v /opt/$JOB_NUBER:$PATH_OF_BUILD $image-name` so now this `/opt/` partition should be shared storage like `nfs` or `sshfs` and that should also be binded with `jenkins-master nodes` so when you navigate to any job workspace you should able to see `/opt/` partition data over there.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a plan...I shall try and get back to you. One quick question here though: when you say shared storage, it means that this should be accessible from inside the docker containers?

Comment: What I am assuming is you are running container on multiple machines when build triggered, correct ? So you want the common storage between all this docker installed VMs/Physical servers. so it should be accessible from out side the docker and inside too becauses at the end it's writing data on physical machine `/opt/` when we do `-v` with `docker run` command.

Comment: my use case is, I have a jenkins slave for which I use yet another docker/docker plugin. I have like 10 jobs bound to this jenkins docker slave, each of which spins up a new container and destroys after the build. I want to make sure that each of this jobs workspace is visible to me from the jenkins UI at any given point of time.

Comment: Got it. So above architecture will help you to even add more docker installed nodes. to server your jobs

Comment: If it get the logic correctly, the steps are: Create a volume on host machine. Share that volume with jenkins master. Run the image using that volume?

Comment: Correct!! You got it.

Comment: I am a naive to docker, Can you edit the solution with the best practices commands?

Comment: @B.TAnand were you able to accomplish this?

Comment: @Can Elmas Nope unfortunately not